# Target map()'ed items one by one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a contact form where the form fields are changed after they are filled.
For example when you fill the email field, you press enter or click the Next button it disappears and the next field appears. There will be different form field types (text, email, select, etc).
What i want to achieve is based on [this](https://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenForm/) form, but it is coded in vanilla js and i want to write it in React from scratch.

For now my basic code is this:

ContactForm.js file:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Fields from "./Fields";

const ContactForm = ({ fields }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='fs-form-wrap' id='fs-form-wrap'>
        <Fields fields={fields} isCurrent={current} />
        <button onClick={() => setCurrent(current + 1)}>Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Fields.js file:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Field from "./Field";

const Fields = ({ fields, isCurrent }) => {

  return (
    <form id='myform' className='fs-form fs-form-full'>
      <ol className='fs-fields'>
        {fields.map((field, index) => {
          return (
            <Field
              placeHolder={field.placeholder}
              title={field.title}
              type={field.type}
              key={index}
              isCurrent={isCurrent}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ol>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Fields;
```

Field.js file:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Field = ({ placeHolder, type, title, isCurrent }) => {

  return (
    <TheField isCurrent={isCurrent}>
      <label className='fs-field-label fs-anim-upper' htmlFor='q2'>
        {title}
      </label>
      <input
        className='fs-anim-lower'
        id='q2'
        name='q2'
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeHolder}
        required
      />
    </TheField>
  );
};

export default Field;

const TheField = styled.li`
  visibility: ${(props) => (props.isCurrent === 0 ? "visible" : "hidden")};
`;
```

Based on this code, initially i get my 2 fields which are coming from my `dummy-data.json` file but when i click on the button, both of them disappear.
I know that my code is still a mess, but i first want to make them appear one by one, then i think i know the logic for the other parts.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT with the solution from @zergski below:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Field from "./Field";
import { BidirectionalIterator } from "./Iterator";

const ContactForm = ({ fields }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);


  const options = { startIndex: 0, loop: false, clamp: true };

  const list = new BidirectionalIterator(fields, options);
  
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='fs-form-wrap' id='fs-form-wrap'>
        <form id='myform' className='fs-form fs-form-full'>
          <ol className='fs-fields'>
            <li>{list}</li>
            {/* {fields.map((field, index) => {
          return (
            <Field
              placeHolder={field.placeholder}
              title={field.title}
              type={field.type}
              key={index}
            />
          );
        })} */}
          </ol>
          {/* <Submit clickHandler={submitClickHandler} text={submitText} /> */}
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => list.next()}>Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create your own iterator... either through the use of generators or a custom class.. here's one I've written

```
export class BidirectionalIterator {
   // TODO: support for other data types
   // #iterate_over: string = 'index'

   static index: number = 0
   static start_index: number = 0
   static looped: boolean = false
   static clamped: boolean = true

   static data: PropertyKey[]
   static ct: number = 0
   static data_len: number = 0

   /** Only supports iterables for now.
    * @param data - the object to be iterated
    * @param options.startIndex - A negative value of less than 0 sets the index at the end of the iterable
    * @param options.loop - loop to the opposite end of iterable (overrides the clamp option setting)
    * @param options.clamp - iterator won't finish upon reaching iterable bounds
    *
    * @caution - DO NOT use a for of/in loop on the iterator if either the loop option is set to true!
   */
   constructor(data: any[] = [], { startIndex = 0, loop = false, clamp = true }: BidirectionalIteratorOptions = {}) {
      BidirectionalIterator.setData(data)
      BidirectionalIterator.start_index = startIndex
      BidirectionalIterator.clamped = loop ? false : clamp
      BidirectionalIterator.looped = loop
   }


   static [Symbol.iterator]() {
      return this
   }

   static setData(data: any) {
      this.data = data

      // TODO: finish support for different collection types
      let [ct, data_len] =
         data instanceof Array ? [1, data.length]
            : data instanceof Map ? [2, data.size]
               : data instanceof Set ? [3, data.size]
                  : [4, -1]

      this.ct = ct
      this.data_len = data_len

      this.resetIndex()
   }

   static resetIndex() {
      this.setIndex(this.start_index < -1 ? this.len : this.start_index)
   }

   static setIndex(idx: number) {
      this.index = idx - 1
   }


   static get len(): number {
      return this.data.length
   }


   // ! well I'm definitely repeating myself....
   static get entry() {
      this.index = num_between(this.index, 0, this.len - 1)
      return {
         index: this.index,
         value: this.data[this.index]
      }
   }

   static get next_entry() {
      this.index = num_between(this.index, 0, this.len - 1)
      return {
         index: this.index + 1,
         value: this.data[this.index] || (this.looped ? this.data[0] : null)
      }
   }

   static get prev_entry() {
      this.index = num_between(this.index, 0, this.len - 1)
      return {
         index: this.index - 1,
         value: this.data[this.index + 1] || (this.looped ? this.data[this.len - 1] : null)
      }
   }


   static next() {
      let value, done

      (done = this.index >= this.len)
         ? this.index = this.len
         : done = ++this.index >= this.len

      // value = this.data[done ? this.len-1 : this.index]
      value = this.data[num_between(this.index, 0, this.len)]


      if (done)
         this.looped
            ? value = this.data[this.index = 0]
            : this.clamped
               ? value = this.data[this.len - 1] : null


      return {
         index: this.index,
         value,
         done
      }
   }


   static prev() {
      let value, done

      (done = this.index <= -1)
         ? this.index = -1
         : done = --this.index <= -1

      // value = this.data[done ? 0 : this.index]
      value = this.data[num_between(this.index, 0, this.len)]


      if (done)
         this.looped
            ? value = this.data[this.len - 1]
            : this.clamped
               ? value = this.data[0] : null


      return {
         index: this.index,
         value,
         done
      }
   }
}
```

so to use it just instantiate the class..

```
const list = new BidirectionalIterator(data_array, options)

// and use with .next() & .prev() methods on mouse input
// e.g this will return the next entry in given array
list.next()
```

it's written in typescript though, so you need to remove all the type declarations

Comment: This is so promising. I'm trying to implement this but for now im getting `ReferenceError: CollectionType is not defined`. I edited the question above so you can see how im trying ti use your iterator. Am i using it wrong?

Comment: sorry, it's the TODO: for support of varying collection types, mission an enum, array is default, can use a 1 instead. I've updated answer

Comment: Even thought i couldn't make you iterator work in my case, (FYI i got `list.next() is not a function` error) i will accept your answer because it directed me to the right track and i finally found a solution. This is the article that helped me a lot: https://dev.to/beccaliz/es6-generators-for-state-management-in-react-h7b

Comment: I'm glad I could help in some way :)

Comment: Hello again @zergski :) After i made a huge round through solutions i came back to your iterator and i think this is the best for me because it is bidirectional and support prev() function. However im having trouble implementing it. I'd appreciate a lot if you would help me on this.

Comment: First i noticed i get the data inside `constructor`, so i need to do `list.constructor.next()` instead of `list.next()`. Then after i do this and lick on the button, i get this error: `ReferenceError: num_between is not defined` which is in `static next() {...}` function (line 99). Can you help me on this somehow?